# Make fails: implicit declaration error

Tags: linux, gcc

I'm trying to compile an application (specifically TVHeadend) which uses **gcc** and I'm getting this error:

```
src/main.c: In function 'main':
src/main.c: error: implicit declaration of function 'COMP_zlib_cleanup'
```

How do I decode from this message where I have to look for fixing it?

I tought it was due a missing **zlib1g-dev**, but it's there. And I can configure the program to avoid using zlib and it still fails.

I'm trying to build on an virtual machine with Debian which uses an old version of gcc (v4.3.2) and I cannot upgrade it; on a recent Ubuntu the same files are compiled correctly without any error or warning.
May the old gcc version be the cause? And, if yes, why?

I'm more interested in a general answer on what is the correct way to undestand and fix general **implicit declaration** errors.

Comment: It sounds very likely that the code you're compiling is newer than the compiler. Have you tried compiling a version of the application that predates the compiler?

Comment: Of course it is, but it's not the first time that I've compiled using that version and it worked every time. They may have added new things or there may be errors in the source, hence I'm asking where I can investigate further to avoid the errors.